# Selection of fragment View depending on selected item ViewModel type

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Target MvvmCross, Android

Objective: A screen (ViewModel/View) where the user can select an animal group (Amphibians, Birds, Fish, Invertebrates, Mammals, Reptiles). When a group has been selected, a Fragment Views will will display information for that animal group. The fields and layout differ per animal group (e.g. fish don't have wings).
Although for this question I have chosen for animal group (which is pretty static), want the list animal groups to be flexible.

Simplified app structure:

- MyApp.Core

  - ViewModels
  - MainViewModel
  - IAnimalGroupViewModel
  - AmphibiansViewModel
  - BirdsBViewModel
  - FishViewModel
- MyApp.Droid

  - Layout

    - MainView
    - AmphibiansFragment
    - BirdsFragment
    - FishFragment
  - Views

    - MainView
    - AmphibiansFragment
    - BirdsFragment
    - FishFragment

The MainView.axml layout file will contain (a placeholder for) the fragment of the displayed animal group.

In WPF or WP8 app I could make use of a ContentPresenter and a Style to automatically display the selected ViewModel with its View.

How could I achieve something like that in Droid?

I could use a Switch/Case in the MainView.cs that sets the Fragment according to the type of the selected ViewGroup. But that means I have to modify the MainView every time I add a new View.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Have answered once... but there's an alternative XML-only based approach in my mind... haven't quite worked out what it is yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently MvvmCross doesn't provide any kind of automatic navigation mechanism for Fragments in the same way that it does for Activities.

However, within your use case, if you wanted to use a navigation approach, then you could automatically build a similar type of automated lookup/navigation mechanism.

To do this, the easiest developer root would probably be to use reflection to find a lookup dictionary for all the fragments

```
 var fragments = from type in this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                 where typeof(IAnimalGroupView)..sAssignableFrom(type)
                 where type.Name.EndsWith("Fragment")
                 select type;
 var lookup = fragments.ToDictionary(
                  x => x.Name.Substring(0, x.Name.Length - "Fragment".Length) 
                              + "ViewModel",
                  x => x);
```

With this in place, you could then create the fragments when they are needed - e.g.

- assuming that you convert the Selection event via an ICommand on the ViewModel into a `ShowViewModel<TViewModel>` call
- and assuming that you have a Custom Mvx presenter which intercepts these ShowViewModel requests and passes them to the activity (similar to the [Fragment sample](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Setup.cs#L22)) - e.g.

  ```
  public class CustomPresenter
      : MvxAndroidViewPresenter
  {
      // how this gets set/cleared is up to you - possibly from `OnResume`/`OnPause` calls within your activities.
      public IAnimalHostActivity AnimalHost { get; set; }

      public override void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
      {
          if (AnimalHost != null && AnimalHost.Show(request))
               return;

          base.Show(request);
      }
  }
  ```
- then your activity could implement `Show` using something like:

  ```
  if (!lookup.ContainsKey(request.ViewModelType.Name))
       return false;

  var fragmentType = lookup[request.ViewModelType.Name];
  var fragment = (IMvxFragmentView)Activator.Create(fragmentType);
  fragment.LoadViewModelFrom(request);

  var t = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
  t.Replace(Resource.Id.my_selected_fragment_holder, fragment);
  t.Commit();
  return true;
  ```

Notes:

- if you aren't using `ShowViewModel` here then obviously this same approach could be adjusted... but this answer had to propose something...
- in a larger multipage app, you would probably look to make this `IAnimalHostActivity` mechanism much more generic and use it in several places.